# NumPy: Make filter array from a (N,2) shaped array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following array:

```
[[4 9]
 [5 4]
 ...
 [2 9]]
```

I want to filter this `arr` array, in a way, that I only have the elements of it, where both elements are between 0 and 7, and discard the rest. My solution, so far, has been to create a filter array, to index it with:

```
filter_array = ((arr >= 0) & (arr <= 7))
```

My problem is, this returns an array of the same shape as `arr`:

```
[[ True False]
 [ True True]
 ...
 [ True False]]
```

Which I can't use to index the original array in the way that I want. I want to discard the entire line, if any of the elements are not between the values I want:

```
#desired output:
[ False
  True
  ...
  False ]
```

I want to solve this in a "numpy-ish" manner, since the array is quite large, so performance is important. (I don't want to just iterate over it with some for loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum in the axis=1 and see if it sums to 2:

```
filtered_array = (filtered_array.sum(1)==2)
```

Another way, where you can use and operator:

```
filtered_array = filter_array[:,0] & filter_array[:,1]
```

Lastly:

```
filter_array = filter_array.all(1)
```

This latter for me is the best way, but you can choose what works for you.

Comment: In the first solution you proposed, you can just multiply each row to avoid checking the sum, namely `filtered_array.prod(1)` will give you 1 as result if and only if both elements are `True`.

Comment: @FBruzzesi, That's true, I guess it is kind of the same thing .all(1) do under the hoods.